# What options are there to expand the inventory?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 1, there were a handful of options to get a bigger inventory/carrying space. Examples are the special bags that offered more slots than four, or bags in which you could stuff weapons and armor.

Is such a feature available in GW2 as well ?  The other day I found a different colored bag  that offered a few more slots than a general bag, but I wonder what the maximum is, and if you can actively seek possession of such items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You can buy or craft more pouches or boxes with various storage sizes and properties (for instance, armorsmiths can craft a 'safe' box that holds 8 items that will not be sorted with compact or moved to collections unless you do so manually).

2) You can also unlock extra pouch/box "slots", via the in-game store.

(At work; can't check the site/wiki to link URLs.)

Comment: Great tip regarding that 'safe' box. While also logical, I found it nevertheless irritating that 'Deposit all collectibles' also deposited my minipet :)

Comment: Still, I'd also like to know what is the maximum capacity for each extra container.

Comment: It varies depending on the exact container type. Standard pouches are 4, I've seen some with 5, the bronze box was 8 and the iron box I'm allowed to craft next has 10 slots...

Comment: There's a new type of storage container that has "invisible" as a pre/suffix, it makes the items in that bag not move when autobanking and won't show in vendors' lists!

Comment: Looking at vendor items, there seem to be crafting components for bags up to at least 20 slots.

Comment: Leatherworkers get a recipe for an 8 slot bag right off the bat.

Comment: Inventory slots cost 400gems and bank rows cost 600gems.

Comment: @Tacroy Yes, so do armoursmiths -- although in their case it's an 8-slot bronze box. You can experiment with additives in the invention screen and come up with some odd combos.